# Auto number a new tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm a very new Google Sheets user trying to get my head around scripts.

I created a macro linked to a button which duplicates a tab but I would like to automatically renumber the new tab with the next number.

At the moment I just get `Copy of Copy of Sheet 1`, `Copy of Copy of Copy of Sheet 1`, etc.

```
function NEWTAB2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E13').activate();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
};
```

Comment: `new Google sheets user trying to get my head around scripts` You are to congratulated. So many users avoid this. Just to clarify: `renumber the new tab with the next number.` So if you have "Sheet1", and you make a copy of "Sheet1", then you would like to name the copy "Sheet2", and so on - where the sheet number is the next number in sequence. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You want to duplicate and rename the active sheet.

The default name of a duplicated sheet is "Copy of SheetX" (where “X” is an integer). You want the name of the duplicated sheet to be "SheetX+1".

So, you need to get the value of "X", add 1, text if the sheet name already exists, and duplicate/rename the active sheet as necessary.

---

**Comments**

- Sequence number of the active sheet

  - `parseInt(tabName.slice(5), 10)`
  - `slice(5)` removes the first 5 characters of the sheet name ("Sheet"); the result = the sequence number as a string
  - `parseInt` converts a string to a number
- test if the next sheet name in the sequence already exists

  - `create a loop` add the loop value to the exiting sheet number to create a number for the duplicated sheet
  - `test if the next sheet number exists`

    - if Yes, then do nothing
    - if No, then duplicate the active sheet and rename the sheet with the new name

---

```
function newTab() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  spreadsheet.getRange('E13').activate();

  // get the existing sheet name and sequence number
  var tabName = spreadsheet.getSheetName()
  var oldSheetNum = parseInt(tabName.slice(5), 10)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The name of the sheet is "+tabName+" and the old sheet number is "+oldSheetNum)

  // the text part of the new sheet numbers
  var sheetNameBase = "Sheet"

  // loop through some numbers to find the next available sheet name
  // testing to see if the proposed sheet name already exists
  for (var i=oldSheetNum+1;i<10;i++){
    // new sheet number
    var newSheetName = sheetNameBase+i
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Proposed new sheet name = "+newSheetName)
    // test if sheet exists
    var sheetExists = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(newSheetName);
    if (!sheetExists) {
      spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet()
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The current name of the duplicated sheet = "+spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName())
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(newSheetName)
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The duplicate sheet name has been changed to "+newSheetName)
      // break out of the loop
      break
    }
    else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The proposed sheet name already exists; selecting next sequential name")
    }
  }
}
```